AWS Glues ETL Job DB Connection Times When Mixing PostgreSQL and MySql
I have an ETL job that I'd like to be able to pull data from both a PostgreSql and a MySql DB.
I add the PG db as a datasource and can query against it no problem. Then, after I add the MySql db, I can query it as well, but all of a sudden I get timeout errors when trying to connect to the PG datasource: 'java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out'.
If I remove the MySql source, sometimes the PG source will work again, sometimes not.
If I start a new project, the same thing will happen. PG source works fine, then if I try to add in a MySql source, the PG source starts to time out.
Both DB connections are added using jdbc.
Anyone have any idea what is happening?
